# Process large dictionary response in chunks for operations

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a large dictionary response, which I then use to create a bulk object. Since it is simple object creation but in bulk, it's taking too much time. I am trying to do it by multiprocessing or thread. So I can create a bulk object in pieces of data (by single file) and store them together at the end.

Here is my function:

```
def create_obj(self, resp):
    school_db = Schools.objects.bulk_create(
        [Schools(
            **{k: v for k, v in value.items()
               })for key, value in resp.items()
         ])
    return school_db
```

and sample of my large dictionary response-

```
response = {
    'A101': {
        'VEG': True,
        'CONTACT': '12345',
        'CLASS': 'SIX',
        'ROLLNO': 'A101',
        'CITY': 'CHANDI',
    },
    'A102': {
        'VEG': True,
        'CONTACT': '54321',
        'CLASS': 'SEVEN',
        'ROLLNO': 'A102',
        'CITY': 'GANGTOK',
    },
}
```

So is there any way to split up the dictionary into 15-20 chunks by which I can use multiprocessing to process?

Comment: use in [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/) and process each page in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

[`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) accepts `batch_size` parameter however I think whaat you really want to do is to return `200` response immediately and perform bulk creation in a background task eg. with `celery`

Comment: Maybe can use [django model transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/) along with these to make sure the entire batch is processed completely.